# Creating an array from form inputs before it is posted to the options database

Tags: plugins, php, functions, options, array

I am creating a plugin and I want to be able to have the user input a starting number and ending number from an options page. When they submit it I want to create an array of the numbers (example starting number 1, ending number 100) and then save it to the options table. So create an array of numbers from 1 to 100. I am not sure how to capture the data after it is submitted and before it goes to the database. I would really appreciate some guidance on how to do this. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can I ask why? Why not just store the selected numbers, because you can always just get the full range of numbers when needed. There's no need to store them all.

Comment: Good question. The reason is I need to assign a specific ID number to each of the numbers in the array. Then once a user claims the number in the array I need to add their email address to it. I will edit my original post to show an example. I will then need to run a query to see if all of the numbers have been used and if so create a new set of numbers. The numbers might not get assigned to an email in order either. I hope this makes sense. I apologize if it doesn't. I appreciate the help.